# Quit the application in iphone by code

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to quit (exit) an app in iPhone4 sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869679/how-to-quit-exit-an-app-in-iphone4-sdk)

I have a close button in the first view of the app. I need to close the application succesfully on button click. I had tried the two cases but not worked.

1. `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminate];`
2. `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] exit(0)];`

Comment: As others have stated in the linked question, do not do this. It is against Apple's design guidelines, and most likely will lead to your application being rejected in the review process. It's also not a very good user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `exit(0);`

No need to call with the instance of UIApplication. But before call the exit method, do whatever you need to do such as saving the state, values if any, etc.,

Answer (score 2):

iOS apps aren't supposed to quit on their own; the user quits/suspends apps using the devices' button. For more on this read [Don't Quit Programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27) in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

If your app has finished whatever task it's meant to do and you would normally exit, you can instead just reset the app's state back to whatever it would be when the app starts. You should probably include some cues in the UI so that the user understands what's happening -- remember, the user is supposed to be in charge here. But if your app has reached it's logical conclusion, it may be that the thing that will feel most "right" to the user will be to go back to the initial state. You often see this with games -- once the game is done, the app goes back to the intro screen and waits for the user to start another game.

Note that both snippets you posted are incorrect. UIApplication doesn't have a `-terminate` method. (NSApplication does have a `-terminate:` method, but it takes a parameter and obviously isn't available in iOS.) Your second example mixes function call syntax with message sending syntax in a way that doesn't make any sense -- I doubt that will even compile.

Answer (score 1):

Similar Thing i am also doing while i want to Quit my application after Show alert i think this may help u...

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

NSLog(@"%@",alertView.title);
if(alertView.title== @"Collision failed")
{
    if(buttonIndex==0)
    {
    //gameState = kGameStateRunning;
    [self loadView];
    [self viewDidLoad];
        count=0;
    }
    else
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}
else 
{
    if(buttonIndex==0)
    {
        //gameState = kGameStateRunning;
        [self loadView];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
    else
    {
        second_stage *obj=[[second_stage alloc]initWithNibName:@"second_stage" bundle:nil];
        obj.count2=count;
        [self presentModalViewController:obj animated:YES];
    }
}
```

simply i am writing exit(0);

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure but acc to HIG, iPhone apps should not be closed.

but you can **Set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend** in your application's plist.When you switch to another app, it will cause the app not to go into the background under iOS4. :)