# How to quit iPhone app with an "intentional exception"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I know Apple frowns upon closing the app because the user might think it crashed.

So how do I make it quit intentionally with an exception that doesn't get caught when the user goes back to the home screen? Also, would this be rejected by the App Store?

Comment: Can you describe the use case as to why you want to terminate the app with an exception?

Comment: I want the app to terminate once a week. Why? Mostly for defensive purposes. I'm afraid the app will accumulate memory due to unforseen memory leaks. I want the app to terminate once a week to relinquish the memory and start anew. this is mostly to prevent issues in the future.

Comment: If you feel that your app has memory leaks (as identified by Instruments) then please focus on fixing those leaks.  You can't possibly expect the user of your application to accept that the app can crash at any point in time (even while using it) because the developer wasn't diligent enough to make it work correctly in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to quit (exit) an app in iPhone4 sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869679/how-to-quit-exit-an-app-in-iphone4-sdk)

Comment: @T Reddy Yup, that's why I said I want it to terminate when the user presses the Home button. It'll seem transparent. Again, I'm not disrupting users at all with what I'm asking.

Comment: @Hisoka - Well that's a different story then...just disable multitasking in your app and when the user hits the home button the OS will terminate the app instead of backgrounding it...

Comment: @T Reddy I don't want to do this every single time the user hits home because loading up will take a few seconds. I want to do this once every week as a "refresh". Lots of things could happen: memory accumulating, and blanks screens that freeze.. situations where users can't even manually quit the app.. they will have to restart their cellphone to reuse it. See how useful my use case can be now?

Comment: @Hisoka - I don't see how useful any use case is when you deliberately exit or crash the app.  If you are writing an app that is *this* unstable, then you need to seriously consider focusing on bug fixing and not trying to simply hack around the problems.

Comment: @T Reddy My app has none of these problems. I was asking this question with the assumption that I have devoted all I can to eliminating all issues/bugs. Now I want ENSURE that even if there is a problem I missed, it won't be a big deal. It's like eating healthy + exercising to prevent cancer in the future.. I don't see why you're against it. To me, it's transparent to the user so it won't disrupt them and it has the possibility of preventing unforseen problems. That's the Holy Grail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 4 app doesn't terminate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154491/iphone-4-app-doesnt-terminate)

Comment: The questions that Caleb and I have pointed to contain ways of disabling the normal multitasking process and causing your application to exit when the user presses the home button.  However, Apple highly discourages this, as indicated in their documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5 Users expect applications to multitask, so if yours doesn't they will respond unfavorably to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the answer to this question:

[Forcing a background application to terminate in iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370853/forcing-a-background-application-to-terminate-in-ios-simulator)

It will tell you how to setup your application to terminate instead of backgrounding when the user hits the home button.

If you don't want to do that, I recommend you should instead release resources when your delegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground` fires. I think that is your safest bet. More than one of us say what you're wanting to do is not ideal.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this answer to another question. It an extract from the Apple Human interface guidelines and should help you understand why you shouldn't quit programatically.

You shouldn't force close an app as the standard way to terminate an application is to press the home button (or use the multitasking bar)

> ## Don’t Quit Programmatically
>
> ---
>
> Never quit an iOS application programmatically because people tend to
>   interpret this as a crash. However, if external circumstances prevent
>   your application from functioning as intended, you need to tell your
>   users about the situation and explain what they can do about it.
>   Depending on how severe the application malfunction is, you have two
>   choices.
>
> **Display an attractive screen that describes the problem and suggests a
>   correction.** A screen provides feedback that reassures users that
>   there’s nothing wrong with your application. It puts users in control,
>   letting them decide whether they want to take corrective action and
>   continue using your application or press the Home button and open a
>   different application
>
> **If only some of your application's features are not working, display
>   either a screen or an alert when people activate the feature.** Display
>   the alert only when people try to access the feature that isn’t
>   functioning.

<sup>[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Apple will most likely reject it as a violation of the human interface guidelines, so it really doesn't matter how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> So how do I make it quit intentionally with an exception that doesn't
>   get caught when the user goes back to the home screen?

**You don't.** If your app is "done," just go back to the initial state. Reset all your variables, release your view controllers, whatever. Pretend that the app actually did terminate, and that the user started it up again. You'll be happy, your users will be happy, and Apple will be happy.

An alternative, if your app truly can't continue for some reason, is to display a message that explains the situation to the user and tells them how to resolve the problem. Leave that message visible until the user leaves the app by pressing the Home button. This can be the only reasonable way to deal with situations where some resource such as network access is missing.

> Also, would this be rejected by the App Store?

Nobody can say that for certain other than Apple, but I think the probability of rejection is high.

Comment: I mainly want to do this because of unforseen circumstances. Yes, if I could reset everything and be 100% guaranteed everything was reset, I'd do that, sure... but in the world of programming, u can't forsee everything.

Comment: @Hisoka Then do your best to explain what happened to the user. Then either go back the start or let the user quit. I'm not sure why you think you can't reset, though... you control your app's initial state.

Comment: @Hisoka BTW, the industry standard name for an unforeseen thing that causes your app to quit: **bug**.

Comment: Yes, of course. But if I could just get the app to terminate once a week, and it'll release all the memory accumulated, that'll prevent a lot of potential issues in the future. That's the Holy Grail.

Comment: @Hisoka What accumulated memory, and what potential issues? If your app leaks memory, fix it. If your app functions poorly in low memory situations, fix it. These are both testable conditions. It sounds like you're just feeling worried and the periodic termination might feel like a safe maneuver. In fact, it sounds from here like you're introducing a bug! ;-) Think of me when you get your first bug report that says "Every once in a while this app crashes for no apparent reason."

Comment: The user only knows it's a crash when it exits in the middle of them using it. They won't know it's a crash when the app terminates when they hit the Home button.